# IOS Core-Data concurrency issues

Tags: core-data, concurrency, nsoperation, master-detail

I once again come about my RSS Reader iApp which, at the moment, is designed the following way:

- Data model: `Category` -> `Feed` -> `Post`
- Master View: `Feed`s grouped by categories
- Detail View: `Post`s for a given `Feed`

All of the views and the app delegate only interact with the same `_mainMOC` (ManagedObjectContext).

Each of the created NSOperations will use its own `_localMOC` which is connnected to the same NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.

When the App starts, it creates for each of the `Feed`s a `fetchOp` NSOperation which it adds to an NSOperationQueue. This should ensure the RSS `Feed`s will be individually downloaded, parsed, then their contents inserted `Post` by `Post` in CoreData.

The AppDelegate observes the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotifications` and merges the modifications if the `notification` it receives is not `_mainMOC`. It then sends  a specific NSNotification to notify the each of the views that a `reloadData` is required.

Questions:

- Do I still need to enclose my _mainMOC `save:` operations in `performBlock` blocks?
- Should each of my views only use a `_localMOC` instead of the `_mainMOC`?
- Isn't it redundant to have each view's local NSFetchedResultsController re-perform a fetch before a `reloadData`?
- Should I make any non-read-only Core-Data Operation a queued NSOperation, even at the view level?
- How could I make all of this smoother (it still isn't and I still have a few horrendous bugs so redesign is a possibility)...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) & 2) It doesn't appear these are absolutely required: we are in the main thread, after all.

3) This couldn't hurt: especially if the NSFecthedResultsController uses a variable  NSPredicate (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586124/why-do-i-have-to-comment-out-my-nspredicate-to-have-nsfetchedresultscontroller-p)).

4) I am going to do it anyway as it doesn't hurt.

5) Keep in touch...