# Why do I have to comment out my NSPredicate to have NSFetchedResultsController populate an UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, concurrency, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a strange bug: if I uncomment my `NSPredicate`, the resulting `UITableView` is empty.

My data Model is the following:
        Category <-->> Feed <-->> Post

I am fetching the `Post`s. `Post.feed` is a `Post`'s `Feed`. `Feed` has an `rss` `NString` property.

Here's the code:

```
    - (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

        // Set up the fetched results controller if needed.
        if (_fetchedResultsController == nil) {
            // Create the fetch request for the entity.
            NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
            // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
            NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Post"
                                                      inManagedObjectContext:_globalMOC];
            [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

            // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
            NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
            NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
            [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

            NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"feed.rss == %@",  _detailItem.rss];
            [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

            // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
            // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
            NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController =
            [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                managedObjectContext:_globalMOC
                                                  sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                           cacheName:nil];
            self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

            self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

            NSError *error = nil;

            if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate.
                // You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful
                // during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert
                // panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
                //
                NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                abort();
            }

        }

        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
```

As I told before, I only see results if I uncomment the `NSPredicate`. I tried with `LIKE`, `==`, `=`, with double and single quotes around `%@`...

BTW, The best would be to directly compare the `Feed` object...

According to Apple, the syntax might not be the issue, but then what?

The `Post`s are created in a separate ManagedObjectController sharing the same PersistentStoreCoordinator. I get the required `Feed`'s objectID in order to associate the new `Post` with its corresponding `Feed` in the child MOC (otherwise I'd get an error regarding associating objects from different MOC).

I also duely merge my MOCs in the main thread whenever the child MOC notifies it of a change.

Basically: if I `NSLog` the `Post`s I have (commented-NSPredicate), I see every `Post` with the relevant RSS `Feed` URL fitting the displayed `Feed` (= `detailItem`).

Anyone can help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange bug: uncommenting an NSPredicate within an NSFetchedResultsController will empty the UITableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529511/strange-bug-uncommenting-an-nspredicate-within-an-nsfetchedresultscontroller-wi)

Comment: Did you notice I wrote that other post as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Eureka!**

The problem was the following: when I create my `NSFetchedResultsController` in my `DetailView`, `_detailItem` is `nil`.

So, even after when setting `_detailItem`, the `NSPredicate` still focus on comparing my feed relationship to a `nil` object.

I solved the problem by refreshing my `NSFetchedResultsController.fetchRequest` in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in the `MasterView` the following way:

```
    Feed *feed;
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        feed = [_filteredCategoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        feed = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    self.detailViewController.detailItem = feed;
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"feed == %@", feed];
    [self.detailViewController.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

Hope this solution might help other people.

Thanks for your help, nickAtStack!

Answer (score 1):

If your **NSFetchedResultsController** is blank then it's pretty sure that you're getting no results through the fetch request and that i'm afraid, because of inappropriate predicate statement or no matching records. i guess the problem is due to presence of wildcard(don't know much about that)
check [NSPredicate Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html) and [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html) to get accurate results through predicates.

Comment: I don't get it, how is that NSPredicate incorrectly worded? `` [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"feed.rss == %@",  _detailItem.rss]``

Comment: what exactly is that feed.rss ? what are the data types of feed.rss and _detailitem.rss

Comment: Hello Nick, feed.rss is an NSString, _detailItem is also a (Feed *) object. I tried with and without quotes, also with simple and double equal sign. I think the problem somehow lies in the (Post *) creation, within an NSOperation declaring its own ManagedObjectContext.

Comment: should I use SELF.feed.rss in my NSPredicate as I read somewhere but not on the Apple doc site? Also what's the actual syntax to compare .feed with _detailItem (both (Feed *) objects)?

Comment: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"feed.rss == %@", _detailItem.rss] looks fine to me.       have you tried direectly passing value to predicate ? like [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"feed.rss ==  rssString"]

Comment: is "feed.rss" your column name ? you have to give your column name as it is there(if you are using wrong name)   e.g. "Post" table having column "feed" ,,then use [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"feed == %@", _detailItem.rss]

Comment: The hierarchy is the following: the NSFetchedResultsController fetches (Post *) objects which have a (Feed *) feed relationship. (Feed *) objects have an (NString *) rss property. so I want the fetched (Post *) objects to be filtered by the (Feed *) _detailItem object.

Comment: try this:    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY feed == %@", _detailItem.rss]

Comment: I will when I come back home... but I think I did before. Let's see.

Comment: ok, let me know what happens, i didn't know you're working with relationships , for that we us "ANY" or "ALL" in predicates..

Comment: Did not work: 'The left hand side for an ALL or ANY operator must be either an NSArray or an NSSet.'